# Creating Dictionary<string, class>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

In C# with Unity i am trying to create a Dictionary of Classes.

All the classes inherit from a base Class (Building Script) which has a number of Virtual Methods

i have set up my Dictionary thus:

```
Dictionary<string, BuildingScript> buildingScripts = new Dictionary<string, BuildingScript>();
```

And am trying to add to the Dictionary thus:

```
buildingScripts.Add("Farm", FarmScript);
buildingScripts.Add("Hunter", HunterScript);
buildingScripts.Add("Fisher", FisherScript);
```

The compiler is recongising the inheritance so i am trying to work out what i have missed.

The error messages are:

> - error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable',
>     `value' or`method group' was expected
> - The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Add(string,
>     BuildingScript)' has some invalid arguments
> - Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type `BuildingScript'

Comment: add object(instance) of type, not type itself

Comment: Have you created instances of `FarmScript, HunterScript and FisherScript`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dictionary has been declared as `Dictionary<string, BuildingScript>`, so its value should be an **instance** of `BuildingScript`.

Consider difference: `FarmScript` itself is type, but `new FarmScript()` is instance of that type.

So your code should look like:

```
buildingScripts.Add("Farm", new FarmScript());
buildingScripts.Add("Hunter", new HunterScript());
buildingScripts.Add("Fisher", new FisherScript());
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not really shown in the posts, but they seem to be the classes to me:

```
FarmScript //class
HunterScript //class
FisherScript //class
```

while what you need are the instances:

```
FarmScript farmScript = new FarmScript(); //instances of the classes
HunterScript hunterScript = new HunterScript();
FisherScript fisherScript = new FisherScript();
```

This should be OK:

```
buildingScripts.Add("Farm", farmScript);
buildingScripts.Add("Hunter", hunterScript);
buildingScripts.Add("Fisher", fisherScript);
```

Comment: If you dropped the word "names" in both places and newed up the instances I'd like your answer.

Comment: Yes, i just worked this out for myself but as you took the time to post the answer i accepted yours... thank you!

Comment: @Wibble No problem. Glad that you figured it out yourself too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved it myself.... though if there are better ways of doing this (and i sure bet there are) then please post them so i can learn.

I changed the Add's to the Dictionary like this:

```
FarmScript bs1 = new FarmScript();
DictionaryStore.buildingScripts.Add("Farm", bs1);
HunterScript bs2 = new HunterScript();
DictionaryStore.buildingScripts.Add("Hunter", bs2);
FisherScript bs3 = new FisherScript();
DictionaryStore.buildingScripts.Add("Fisher", bs3);
```

Problems all solved!

Comment: Glad that you figure it out! ;)

Comment: The only way of doing it is creating an instance of each class, which you have done. You can save yourself the extra lines by just skipping the variable declarations and following Andy's example - but this is just personal taste as doing so doesn't change the way the application operates, or how the objects are stored. Overall, both methods work just fine and are exactly the same thing at low levels. Good job. :)